# Polynomial Ideal with fixed basis

Tags: polynomials, groebner-basis

I'm looking for the algorithms associated with the two Magma functions PolynomialWithFixedBasis and Coordinates.
In particular, if $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ is a Gröbner Basis (in decreasing order),
I would like to compute some polynomial coordinates $\{h_{i,j}\}$
such that whenever $g_i \in \langle g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n\rangle$, we have
$g_i=\sum_{j=i+1}^n{h_{i,j}g_j}$.
The two functions PolynomialWithFixedBasis and Coordinates do the job,
with

$$I:=\text{Ideal With Fixed Basis}([G[j] : j\ in\ [i+1..n]]);$$

$$H:=\text{Coordinates}(I,G[i]);$$

But I would like to understand how they work. Thank you!